# Solid State Battery vs Lithium (ion or polymer) Battery

Tags: battery

**Background**: It's a hardware related question. I was suppose where should I ask this question, after reading https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57998/hardware-questions-and-stack-exchange I am asking this question here.

[Apple Invents Charging Techniques for Solid State Batteries](http://www.patentlyapple.com/patently-apple/2013/07/apple-invents-charging-techniques-for-solid-state-batteries.html)

[Toyota: solid-state batteries coming in 2020, 3-4 times better than li-ion](http://green.autoblog.com/2013/03/12/toyota-solid-state-batteries-in-2020-better-than-lithium/)

Solid State Battery is still a research topic. So I am not getting good resources regarding this. For this reason I am approaching here.

**My Question:** What are the core points regarding Solid State Battery vs Lithium (ion or polymer) Battery?